# How do I create a new pane within an Eventhandler?

Tags: javafx, pane

I am creating a questionnaire and want multiple 'pages'. Each page is a pane. I want to create a 'next button' that will navigate the user to the next pane where another list of questions will be waiting for them to answer. What do I write in the event handler for javafx? By creating a new pane will my answers from pane1 be safe still?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example. I have declared the following as global variables: `questions, answers, currentQuestion`. `Questions` are a list of strings that contain the questions. `Answers` are a list of strings that contain the user answers. `CurrentQuestion` is the index in which is the current question.

When a `ButtonAction` (click) is called, I update the `currentQuestion` (adding 1), so it goes to the next question. I have passed in the `Stage` as variable so I can update it when I click on the button.

What it does is, it calls a new constructor for the `Scene`. Then, I use `setScene` on the `Stage` to update the grahics.

Another way to do this would be to use a `State Machine`. Make a class that changes the `Pane`. Then, the `Button Action` will change the state of that class (For example, it will have Integer states, of 1, 2, 3 (3 different questions).

```
    public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

    int curPage = 1;
    String [] questionnaire = new String[]{
            "Why is the sun blue?", "Why is iPhones better than Androids", "Why are moons bad for your skin",
            "Who am I?", "To be or not to be?", "Yes or no?", "Will you rain on my parade?", "Etc questions"
        };
    String [] answer;
    Scene s;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        answer = new String[questionnaire.length];

        Pane curPane = differentPage(questionnaire[curPage-1], questionnaire.length, stage);

        s = new Scene(curPane);
        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void setSceneAgain(Stage stage){
        Pane curPane = differentPage(questionnaire[curPage-1], questionnaire.length, stage);
        s = new Scene(curPane);
        stage.setScene(s);
       }

    public Pane differentPage(String question, int numQuestions, final Stage stage){
        Pane p = new Pane();

        VBox vbo = new VBox();

        Label l = new Label("Page: " + curPage);
        Label r = new Label(question);
        vbo.getChildren().addAll(l,r);

        // 10 = lastpage
        if(curPage < numQuestions){
            Button nextButton = new Button("Next");
            nextButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override 
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        // set answer[curPage-1] here to whatever the person chose
                        curPage++;
                        setSceneAgain(stage);
                    }
                });
            vbo.getChildren().add(nextButton);
        } else {
            Button finishButton = new Button("Finish");
            finishButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                    //finish event
                }
            });
            vbo.getChildren().add(finishButton);
        }

         p.getChildren().add(vbo);
        return p;
    }

}
```